# Promise with async function is not waiting to be fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, jasmine, allure

I am struggling with the issue of Promise and async/await for last two days. I am trying to configure my protractor.conf.js that would get the browser name just at the starting of the suit and will join with the suit name. I have written jasmine allure reporter code in customized way so that I can get browser name in asynchronously and then use with the suit name. But nothing working properly. In the code I have tried, I get only suit name. Browser name in few seconds later. As a result I could not use that browser name in suit name.  Here is my code in detail

**Edited**

```
   var AllureReporter = function CustomJasmine2AllureReporter(userDefinedConfig, allureReporter) {


    let browser = {
     getCapabilities: function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({
                    get: str => str
                 });
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
};

    var result;
    let bName = (async () => {
        try {
            var result = (await browser.getCapabilities()).get('Browser Name');
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
            return "Error or smth"
        }
        })();

        this.suiteStarted = function(suite) {
                this.allure.startSuite(suite.fullName + result);
                console.log(suite.fullName + result);

        };

        // other methods like spec done,, spec description.

    }
```

the index code from Allure that can be changed is

```
'use strict';
var assign = require('object-assign'),
            Suite = require('./beans/suite'),
            Test = require('./beans/test'),
            Step = require('./beans/step'),
            Attachment = require('./beans/attachment'),
            util = require('./util'),
            writer = require('./writer');

function Allure() {
    this.suites = [];
      this.options = {
            targetDir: 'allure-results'
            };
        }
    Allure.prototype.setOptions = function(options) {
            assign(this.options, options);
        };

        Allure.prototype.getCurrentSuite = function() {
            return this.suites[0];
        };



        Allure.prototype.startSuite = function(suiteName, timestamp) {

        this.suites.unshift(new Suite(suiteName,timestamp));
        };


    module.exports = Allure;
```

and the Suit.js class

```
    function Suite(name, timestamp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.start = timestamp || Date.now();
        this.testcases = [];
    }
    Suite.prototype.end = function(timestamp) {
        this.stop = timestamp || Date.now();
    };


    Suite.prototype.addTest = function(test) {
        this.testcases.push(test);
    };

    Suite.prototype.toXML = function() {
        var result = {
            '@': {
                'xmlns:ns2' : 'urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru',
                start: this.start
            },
            name: this.name,
            title: this.name,
            'test-cases': {
                'test-case': this.testcases.map(function(testcase) {
                    return testcase.toXML();
                })
            }
        };


        if(this.stop) {
            result['@'].stop = this.stop;
        }

        return result;
    };

    module.exports = Suite;
```

I am getting this output after edited the question.the result is undefined in the suit name

```
Executing 7 defined specs...

Test Suites & Specs:
Test for correct login undefined

1. Test for correct login 
(node:9764) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to 
security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), 
Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
√ Navigate to the login page (5520ms)
√ Click onto language button (406ms)
√ English Language is selected (417ms)
√ Correct user name is written into email field (609ms)
√ Correct password is written into password field (486ms)
√ Login button is clicked and home page is opened with Machine on left top
```

menu (5622ms)
    √ Logout button is clicked and redirect to login page (4049ms)

7 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 17.127 seconds

I want to get browser name after the the line 'Test Suites & Specs:' and want to add the name with suit name.

Comment: I am assuming, at this is pulled straight from my arse, that the issue is arising because you wrap `await Promise()` with parentheses in order to get the `browserName` afterwards. Split this over two lines, await a promise and then on the next line access the result of the await and ask for the name, give it a go. Again, i can be totally wrong

Comment: @Dellirium Could you please give me an example of that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oxbhf3vd/1/ this is what I understood you wanted

Comment: Key takeaway being, within the async function you need to return a value

Comment: @Dellirium I have edited my code based on your answer but found new error now. I gave my new error in question

Comment: I am not sure what you are attempting to do at this point, but in your `.then` attached to the async `bName` you are passing a function and not giving it any parameters, so the returned result is not available in your `.then` callback.

Comment: @Dellirium  I have edited one more time. Now the result is undefined. But could you please tell me how can I get the browser name with the suit name. I am really struggling with that issue from last two days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186655/discussion-between-dellirium-and-nick-tec).

Answer (score 0):

The function where you want to use await should be async.
I have made a small example for you. hope it will help

```
//The function we want to use wait in should be async!
async function myFunction() {
    //Using callback
    thisTakeSomeTime().then((res) => console.log(res)); //Will fire when time out is done. but continue to the next line

    //Using await
    let a = await thisTakeSomeTime();
    console.log(a);//will fire after waiting. a will be defined with the result.
}

function thisTakeSomeTime() {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{res("This is the result of the promise")}, 5000)
    })
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: @Ido_Cohen I have edited my code and foiund new error which I described in question

Comment: your scope is still not a async. as I said. to use await the whole scope/function should be async function type.

var AllureReporter = async function CustomJasmine2AllureReporter(userDefinedConfig, allureReporter)...